What are all $n \times n$ matrices $A_n$ such that $A_n^m=A_n$?
I am revisiting linear algebra and in my notes there are some question that I wanted to search for their answer and completely forgot about them and this is one of them:
Given $n,m$ what are the $n \times n$ matrices $A_n$ such that $A_n^m=A_n$?
When $n=1$ for all $m$  the matrices that work are $[0]$ and all $m$ roots of unity , when $n=2, m=2k:$
$$ A_n=\left[
\begin{array}\ 
  \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4ab}}{2}& a\\
  b&\ \frac{1\mp \sqrt{1-4ab}}{2}
\end{array}
\right] $$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ Also this matrix will work for all $m$. Are the any matrices that work only for of prime $m>2$?
If a matrix work for a prime number $m$ then it will work for all of its multiples.
My questions are

How to find a general form for any $n$, $m$?
Is there is a way to determine the entries for $A_n$ in the general form?


Hint: $A^m=A$ is equivalent to $A(A^{m-1}-I)=0$. So either $A=0$ or $A^{m-1}=I$.

@Martigan in the case where m =2 there are other matrices than $A=0$ and $A=I$

You can use the same approach as in your previous question. Here it is even easier,because such a matrix is necessarily diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. $A$ will be similar to a diagonal matrix all of whose diagonal entries are either $0$ or a complex $n$th root of unity. By contrast, your approach trying to use equations to determine the entries avoids all the useful tools of linear algebra in favor of mindless algebraic manipulation. It is  terrible way to try to review linear algebra.

@Martigan The ring of matrices has zero divisors, so your last step is invalid.

$A$ satisfies the polynomial $x^m-x$, which over $\mathbb{C}$ has no repeated roots. So the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits and has no repeated roots. Thus $A$ is diagonalizable and all its diagonal entries are roots of $x^m-x$.
Therefore, $A$ is of the form $PDP^{-1}$, where $P$ is an invertible matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are either $0$ or a complex $m$th root of unity.
